# MAWS.py IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

MAWS is a program that searches for aptamers (short DNA/RNA sequences) based on a target molecule(protein, peptide). After several loops it should output an aptamer associated to the target molecule. MAWS uses Amber/AmberTools to make what it should. After calculating the first nucleotide files 'DGN', 'DAN', 'DTN', 'DCN' the program stops with the error

> "IndexError: list index out of range"

I updated the MAWS.py to MAWS_rev1.pyscript with the newest amber force field. Before doing this, the mentioned files 'DGN', 'DAN', 'DTN', 'DCN'could not be obtained. Related to the error, I do not know how to proceed as I am not familiar with python programming.

The source code MAWS.py can be downloaded via GitHub 
https://github.com/igemsoftware/Heidelberg_15

Some output after running MAWS:

> bcramer@schrodinger:~/workdir-MAWS$ python3 MAWS_rev1.py -b 0.01 -i 200 -s 200 -l 15 -t 0.01 -f mol2  -y  HYBRID  PATH INFILE
>   ['DGN', 'DAN', 'DTN', 'DCN']
>   Choosing from candidates ...
>   Constructing Ligand/Aptamer complex ...
>   Constructing Ligand/Aptamer complex ...
>   .................etc................
>   Loading Aptamer/Ligand complex ...
>   multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
>   """
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/bcramer/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
>       result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
>     File "/home/bcramer/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
>       return list(map(*args))
>     File "MAWS_rev1.py", line 1090, in initial
>       ligand_range = get_ligand_range(aptamer_top.topology)
>     File "MAWS_rev1.py", line 197, in get_ligand_range
>       return [get_ligand(topology)[0], len(get_ligand(topology))]
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>   """

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "MAWS_rev1.py", line 1357, in 
>       positions_and_Ntides = loop()
>     File "MAWS_rev1.py", line 1237, in loop
>       pos_Nt_S_task = pool.map(initial, alphabet)
>     File "/home/bcramer/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
>       return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
>     File "/home/bcramer/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
>       raise self._value
>   IndexError: list index out of range
>   end of output

The output should look like a sequence of 15 letters using the letters G,A,C,U and T. In my specific case (PC w. 4 cores) I estimate that MAWS will take ca three days to give the results. So, I do not expect anybody to run the program but help me to make it run providing detailed procedures based on the errors that may arise.